# Is it a correct sentence? Can noun phrase be a sentence's apposition?

Tags: sentence

> “Eye contact and smiles” can signal availability and confidence, a common-sense notion supported in studies by psychologist Monica Moore.

Is “notion” the apposition of the first sentence? Or "which is" is omitted after the comma?

Comment: It is all one sentence. _Notion_ refers to the statement in the first clause. _Which is_ could be included, but before _supported_.

Comment: It's poorly written. I'd want something more heavy-duty after the independent clause, and preferably (as you suggest) at least a 'speech tag' such as 'which is' either where you suggest or where Kate suggests. But I'd prefer even greater clarity. ' 
_Eye contact and smiles_ can signal availability and confidence. This is a common-sense notion the truth of which is supported by the results of studies carried out by psychologist Monica Moore.'